# remove some newline but not all in Python

Tags: python, list, foreach, newline

I have data in this format

```
Picture
'#Type'
'10', '10'
000000000000000
110000110110000
Picture2
'#Type2'
'10', '10'
000000000000000
110000111110000
```

I could read in the file using

```
sourcefile.read().splitlines()
```

but then line 4 and 5 will be two items in a list. eg the list would be

```
[picture],[#type],[10,10],[000000000000000],[110000110110000],...
```

But my goal is to concatenate `[000000000000000]` and `[110000110110000]`, namely line 4 and 5 and make them one item. The end result would be something like

```
[Picture],
['#Type'],
['10', '10'],
[000000000000000110000110110000]
```

How can I achieve this? Better yet how can I make them 4 as a group in a nested list? Many thanks.

Comment: In other words, is the rule that you want to split on newlines unless the newlines are between two numbers?

Comment: not any two numbers, just the ones after '10', '10'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as infile:
    data = infile.read()
split_data = data.split('\n')
req_list = range(3, len(split_data), 5)
flag = False
for ind, val in enumerate(split_data):
    if flag:
        print([split_data[ind-1] + val])
        flag = False
        continue
    if ind not in req_list:
        print([val])
    else:
        flag = True
```

Output:

```
['Picture']
["'#Type'"]
["'10', '10'"]
['000000000000000110000110110000']
['Picture2']
["'#Type2'"]
["'10', '10'"]
['000000000000000110000111110000']
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain a bit more about this logic?

Comment: after every five line you get the binary numbers, so a `range` function id used to create a list with the required line numbers. Whenever the line number is found a flag is raised, and the raised flag is used to append the binary digits

Comment: for the first iteration in for loop, the flag will be set to true right? but what happens in the 2nd iteration? how does split_data[ind-1] + val concatenate the two binary numbers?

Comment: at the first iteration the flag is not set to true, the flag is set to true only when the line number is 4, to understand it better just print the values, so that you can understand it better

Answer (score 1):

You can just re-iterate over the array once its done.

```
arr = sourcefile.read().splitlines()
```

After you have the array you can extract the inputs that are longer than 9 characters

```
arrOfLargeNumbers = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 9, arr)
```

Then remove the old ones from the array and add the new one

```
arr.remove(arrOfLargeNumbers[0])
arr.remove(arrOfLargeNumbers[1])
arr.append(f'{arrOfLargeNumbers[0]}{arrOfLargeNumbers[1]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always have 4 lines per picture, then you can split the lines like you're doing right now - then merge every 3rd and 4th line to get the result

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("path_to_your_input_file", "r") as f:
lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()]
new_lines = []
last_was_digit = 0
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.isdigit() and last_was_digit == 0:
        new_lines.append(["".join([line, lines[i+1]])])
        last_was_digit = 1
    elif last_was_digit == 1:
        last_was_digit = 0
    else:
        new_lines.append([line])
```

So this code does the job by reading from the file. It's not elegant but it works.

The output:

```
> [['Picture'], ["'#Type'"], ["'10', '10'"], ['000000000000000110000110110000']
> ['Picture2'], ["'#Type2'"],["'10', '10'"], ['00000000000000011000011111000']]
```